# chromium: sync is paused - sign in again

Tags: google-chrome, sync, chromium

For the past month, chromium sync does not work, and google does not remember my sign in.

in the upper right corner it shows "paused".

When I log in into sync, nothing happens, no error message, but nothing changes

Further, my google and youtube sign in only stays signed in for current session.

I have to sign in each time again and again, and it does not remember my password.

This happened on my old profile which I used for years. I did not change anything.

But now I tried creating new clean profile on different laptop, completely unrelated from my first profile, different version of chromium, and there I have the same problem exactly.

I don't have auto-clear cookies, or "Clear cookies and site data when you close all windows" active

And this is not some problem with my google account. I have same google account signed in in firefox, and there is no problem there (google, youtube)